# How to scale out.pop up image when i hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an image that i want to scale out when it has hovered.

code is written with react and css. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/jatinmehrotra/a1fdb3aeb6143152a525f878702b0e25) which include style sheet as well as js code

react/js code

```
    import React from 'react';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';

import ScreenHeading from '../../utilities/ScreenHeading/ScreenHeading';
import ScrollService from '../../utilities/ScrollService';
import Animations from '../../utilities/Animations';
import './Certificates.css';
import clf from '../../img/Certs/clf.png';
import shape from '../../img/Certs/shape-bg.png';

export default function Certificate(props) {
  let fadeInScreenHandler = (screen) => {
    if (screen.fadeInScreen !== props.id) return;
    Animations.animations.fadeInScreen(props.id);
  };

  const fadeInSubscription =
    ScrollService.currentScreenFadeIn.subscribe(fadeInScreenHandler);

  const options = {
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    nav: true,
    animateIn: 'bounceInRight',
    animateOut: 'bounceOutRight',
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      768: {
        items: 1,
      },
      1000: {
        items: 3,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ScreenHeading
        title={'Certifications'}
        subHeading={'I love validating my skills'}
      />
      <section className="testimonial-section fade-in" id={props.id || ''}>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <OwlCarousel
              className="owl-carousel"
              id="testimonial-carousel"
              {...options}
            >
              <div className="col-lg-12">
                <div className="testi-item">
                  <div className="testi-comment">
                    <p>
                      <i className="fa fa-quote-left" />
                      Learning about core aws services, shared responsibility
                      model and billing and pricing concepts was an eyeopener
                      for me as a cloud engineer.
                      <i className="fa fa-quote-right" />
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="client-info">
                    <img src={clf} alt="no internet connection"></img>
                    <h5>AWS CLF-01</h5>
                    <p></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="col-lg-12">
                <div className="testi-item">
                  <div className="testi-comment">
                    <p>
                      <i className="fa fa-quote-left" />
                      Coming Soon 
                      <i className="fa fa-quote-right" />
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="client-info">
                    {/* <img src={mike} alt="no internet connection"></img> */}
                    <h5>AWS SAA</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-12">
                <div className="testi-item">
                  <div className="testi-comment">
                    <p>
                      <i className="fa fa-quote-left" />
                      Coming Soon 
                      <i className="fa fa-quote-right" />
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="client-info">
                    {/* <img src={clf} alt="no internet connection"></img> */}
                    <h5>AWS DVA</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </OwlCarousel>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div className="footer-image">
        <img src={shape} alt="Phot0 not responding" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css

```
   .testimonial-section {
  padding: 80px 0 80px;
  background-image: url('../../../src/assets/Certificates/bg-1.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.testimonial-section::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #1f2235;
}
.footer-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -110px;
}
.footer-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
}

.testimonial-section .testi-item {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 0px;
}

.testimonial-section .testi-item p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.testimonial-section .testi-item p .fa-quote-left {
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: tomato;
}
.testimonial-section .testi-item p .fa-quote-right {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: tomato;
}

.testimonial-section .client-info {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.testimonial-section .client-info img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-color: black;
  left: 30px;
  top: -4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.testimonial-section:hover .client-info img {
  transform: scale3D(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
}
.testimonial-section .client-info h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0 0 2px 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I can't immediately see what is wrong. Can you put a working snippet into your question which we can run and which demonstrates the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have included public gist which includes css sheet and js file. maybe that can help you to identify problem in detail.
https://gist.github.com/jatinmehrotra/a1fdb3aeb6143152a525f878702b0e25

Comment: Please put working snippet into your question - not offsite.

Comment: added the complete working snippet @AHaworth

Comment: I don't see a snippet I can run direct from your question.

Comment: that would be little dicey for me as if i have to convert this into html, js and css and the post a fiddle/snippet, is it possible to work with the code i have provided?

Comment: Check in the dev tools if any default style from owl carousel is interfering. in the add a !important after scale like so and check.

transform: scale3D(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) !important;

Comment: i dont think so any style from carousel is interfering, i could find one style which was using transform but i think it i irrelevant `element.style {
    transform: translate3d(-1140px, 0px, 0px);
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    width: 3420px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try writing like this

```
.testimonial-section:hover .client-info img {
  transform: scale3D(1.5,1.5,1.5);
}
```

or

```
.testimonial-section .client-info img:hover {
  transform: scale3D(1.5,1.5,1.5);
}
```

Comment: i tried both, didn't work

Comment: I have added public gist for better understanding

Comment: Can you add a display: inline-block or block to the img tag

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a example of it

Answer (score 0):

In this case `transform: scale(1.5);` should work. This is a working example (not with your code)

```css
.image-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.image-box img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.image-box img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
  <div class="image-box">
    <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v2/25/default/dark/1.0" alt="">
  </div>
```

With your HTML/CSS

```css
.client-info img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-color: black;
  left: 30px;
  top: -4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.client-info h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0 0 2px 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.client-info:hover img {
  transform: scale3D(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="client-info">
    <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v2/25/default/dark/1.0" alt="no internet connection"></img>
    <h5>AWS CLF-01</h5>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: tried, didnt work

Comment: Can you create a fiddel with your existing code?

Comment: i would need to convert into plain html js, with css. that would be little difficult

Comment: I just checked your relavant html/css code which is belong to `client-info` section and it seems to be working.

Comment: I tried the edited version, it didn't work also in my CSS there is `.testimonial-section` under which `client info` exist.

Comment: replace `.testimonial-section:hover .client-info img {` with `.testimonial-section:hover img {` and try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241711/discussion-between-jatin-mehrotra-and-user3733831).